# git merge different repositories?

Tags: git, git-svn

I've been using SVN for all my projects.
Sometimes project B is originating as a copy from project A.
When project A has a generic change, I can use `svn merge A` within directory B and it will merge those changes.

Now, if I wanted to use git. I don't like having all my projects in the same repository since I then have to clone *everything* and can't pick just one project like in SVN.
But having one repository for each project, how do I go about doing the same like I did earlier with SVN?

**The question is:**
What's the best way to structure it if I want several subprojects that really all relates to one original project and to keep them in sync? And that I also want to be able to check them out separately

Comment: You'd probably better have a look at git-submodule (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html).

Comment: @Jefromi but the source files are basically from the same history, this would mean I have two copies of the files? I think submodule is more for keeping track of external libraries that you include as separate files (not merge)?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see that you said B was a copy of A. Reading your "the question is", where you said "subprojects...relating to one original project...in sync" I assumed you meant taking out chunks of that original project, but keeping them in sync in the metaproject.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you have two projects, `proj1` and `proj2` and want to merge changes of `proj1` into `proj2`, you would do it like this:

```
# in proj2:
git remote add proj1 path/to/proj1
git fetch proj1
git merge proj1/master # or whichever branch you want to merge
```

I believe this does the same thing as what you were doing with SVN.

Comment: But will merge change #2 track that we already merged change #1 doing it this way?
I had to re-merge all changes (and correct conflicts) for all changes every time a new change was added if I remember correct. This didn't happen the SVN-way

Comment: Of course, merge works as usual. You do not have to "remerge all changes". This is nothing more than the usual merge, the one that you would use with a distant server.

Comment: What if I don't have a remote? I would like to do the same (merge projA into projB) but I'm working only locally without remotes.

Comment: @LeoHolanda Local files count as remote as far as git is concerned.

Comment: @LeoHolanda You have point here. I had to denote local repo in URL format, such as file:///Users/abc/path/to/my/repo/.git

Comment: I'd suggest to use `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag in merge to allow merge histories that do not share a common ancestor (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

Comment: Remotes can be just paths: `git remote add r1 ../r1`. `--allow-unrelated-histories` is not recommended, it's [required](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.26.2/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L65) since `git >= 2.9` to merge branches from different repositories.